# ReactJs Calling parent function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am sorry if it is duplicate. I am passing parent function to child but when I use this method in child it give me this error
_this2.props.changeAppMode is not a function

I tried stackover flow already answered questions but can't able to resolve it. I am a newbie so might be I am missing some other concept

Following are my components

Parent Component

```
class Users extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentMode: 'read',
            userId: null
        };

        this.changeAppMode = this.changeAppMode.bind(this);
    }

    changeAppMode(newMode, userId) {
        this.setState({currentMode: newMode});

        if (userId !== undefined) {
            this.setState({userId: userId});
        }
    }

    render() {

        var modeComponent =
            <ReadUserComponent
                changeAppMode={this.changeAppMode}/>;

        switch (this.state.currentMode) {
            case 'read':
                break;
            case 'readOne':
                modeComponent = <ViewUser />;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return modeComponent;
    }
}
export default Users;
```

Child

```
class ReadUserComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUsers();
    }

    render(){
        const users = this.props.users;
        return (
            <div className='overflow-hidden'>
                <h1>Users List </h1>
                <TopActionsComponent changeAppMode={this.props.changeAppMode} />

                <UsersTable
                    users={users}
                    changeAppMode={this.props.changeAppMode} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReadUserComponent.propTypes = {
    users: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    fetchUsers: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        users: state.users
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchUsers })(ReadUserComponent);
```

Child of Child [This component calling parent function]

```
class TopActionsComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <a href='#'
                   onClick={() => this.props.changeAppMode('create')}
                   className='btn btn-primary margin-bottom-1em'> Create product
                </a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

export default TopActionsComponent;

Thanking you in anticipation. Really appreciate your help

Sorry if it is duplicate but I am kind of a stuck in it

Comment: are you sure it is not working? I just tried to recreate it in a hello world type example and it seems to be doing its job. What is the outcome you are expecting?

Comment: In case it helps, the simple example can be found in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/09e93seL/1/

Comment: Yes, its working the silly mistake is on my end. Thanks for you all. *Mayank Shukla* told me to print props in every stage and that did the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it's related to binding in child component. Could you try below piece of code while passing props into child component.
    `<TopActionsComponent changeAppMode={::this.props.changeAppMode} />`

Comment: Now giving this error

**Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined**

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it solved the same issue i was facing.

In `ReadUserComponent` Component:

```
<TopActionsComponent changeAppMode={this.changeAppMode.bind(this)} />
```

Define this function in ReadUserComponent:

```
changeAppMode(type){
    this.props.changeAppMode(type);
}
```

In TopActionsComponent Component:

```
<a href='#' onClick={this.changeAppMode.bind(this,'create')}
   className='btn btn-primary margin-bottom-1em'> Create product
</a>
```

Define this function in TopActionsComponent Component:

```
changeAppMode(type){
   this.props.changeAppMode(type);
}
```

Comment: Now no error showing in console but function is not firing. I placed a console.log in my parent function but its not diplaying 


changeAppMode(newMode, userId) { this.setState({currentMode: newMode}); if (userId !== undefined) { this.setState({userId: userId}); } console.log(this.state.currentMode); }

Comment: edit this part onClick={this.changeAppMode.bind(this,'create')}

Comment: put the console in each changeAppMode() and see whether its going through all or not.

Comment: I checked in all components but its not showing in props of ReadUserComponent

The first Child of Parent

Comment: Props from ReadUserComponent
`ObjectaddFlashMessage: ()children: nullfetchUsers: ()isAuthenticated: truelocation: Objectparams: Objectroute: ObjectrouteParams: Objectrouter: Objectroutes: Array[2]users: Array[0]__proto__: Object`

Comment: i think function calling is proper, just check the parameter you are passing at each level, check the event parameter also.

Answer (score 0):

okay. try this. I think it should work.

`<ReadUserComponent changeAppMode={() => this.changeAppMode}/>;`

`<UsersTable
                    users={users}
                    changeAppMode={() => this.props.changeAppMode} />`

Comment: Now no error showing in console but function is not firing. I placed a console.log in my parent function but its not diplaying

changeAppMode(newMode, userId) {
        this.setState({currentMode: newMode});

        if (userId !== undefined) {
            this.setState({userId: userId});
        }

        console.log(this.state.currentMode);
    }